# What's the difference between char[] & char* when declare inside struct?

Tags: c

I'm trying to look into a piece of code, and something confused me.

When we use structure below:

```
    struct sdshdr {
        int len;
        int free;
        char buf[];
    };
```

We will allocate memory like this:

```
    struct sdshdr *sh;
    sh = zmalloc(sizeof(struct sdshdr)+initlen+1);
```

So, what's the difference between `char[]` & `char*` when buff has been declared inside struct?

Is `char[]` means continues address?

Comment: Declaring `char buf[] = "Hello, world!";` will not cause an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct sdshdr {
        int len;
        int free;
        char buf[];
    };


struct shshdr *p = malloc(sizeof(struct shshdr));

       +---------+----------+-----------------+ 
p -->  | int len | int free | char[] buf 0..n |  can be expanded 
       +---------+----------+-----------------+ 

struct sdshdr {
        int len;
        int free;
        char *buf;
    };

struct shshdr *p = malloc(sizeof(struct shshdr));

       +---------+----------+-----------+ 
p -->  | int len | int free | char* buf | cannot be expanded, fixed size
       +---------+----------+-----------+ 
                                   |
                            +-----------+
                            |           | 
                            +-----------+
```

in the first case this is valid:

```
struct shshdr *p = malloc(sizeof(struct shshdr)+100); // buf is now 100 bytes
...
struct shshdr *q = malloc(sizeof(struct shshdr)+100);

memcpy( q, p, sizeof(struct shshdr) + 100 );
```

Comment: i think i got it, 3ks~

Answer (score 4):

The difference is simple `char buf[]` declares a flexible array; `char * buf` declares a pointer. Arrays and pointers are just not the same, in many ways. For instance, you'll be able to assign directly to a pointer member after initialization, but not to an array member (you'll be able to assign to the entire struct).